# How to pass value to the request action url in el-upload?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, data-binding, element-ui

`<el-upload class="upload" action="http://127.0.0.1:5000/upload/email" :file-list="fileList" >`

Here i have used element UI library and I need to pass email value to the  *'action'* url to end like `base_url/upload/${email}`. But this way doesn't work here in binding the value, because it takes the whole url as a string.

```
export default {
  name: "**",
  data() {
    return {
      base_url: "http://127.0.0.1:5000",
      email: email,
      fileList: []
    }
}
```

What needs to be done here for binding data to the action so that it does post request with the help of el-upload having base_url and email data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing `action` to `:action` worked for me :)
which will be like :-

```
<el-upload
 class="upload"
 :action="base_url+'/upload/'+email"
 :file-list="fileList"
>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use computed properties and set it to action attr of the element.

```
computed: {
    actionAttr: function () {
      return `${this.base_url}/${this.email}
    }
  }
```

more info https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/computed.html